# Why doesn't my UIButton's selected property set correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm really at a loss for words:

```
DDLogVerbose(@"%@", ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode & SO2DrawModeEraser) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
kMenu.eraserButton.selected = ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode & SO2DrawModeEraser);
DDLogVerbose(@"%@", kMenu.eraserButton);
DDLogVerbose(@"%@", kMenu.eraserButton.selected ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

produces this output

> Verbose     2012-08-05 16:21:05.391 | YES
>   Verbose      2012-08-05 16:21:05.391 | < UIButton: 0x6cfa380; frame = (187 10; 59 59); opaque = NO; tag = 3; layer = < CALayer: 0x6c37cc0>>
>   Verbose      2012-08-05 16:21:05.391 | NO

Clearly, the value of `selected` *should* be `YES`, yet it is `NO`...what is going on here?

**WEIRD UPDATE** : The below code produces a very unnerving result:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
btn.selected = 8;
btn.enabled = 8;
NSLog(@"Button is selected : %@, Button is enabled : %@", btn.selected ? @"YES" : @"NO", btn.enabled ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

> Button is selected : NO, Button is enabled : YES

**LAST UPDATE** : Forget about the C-standard thing since `BOOL` is actually a `signed char`.  However, I think I know the reason why enabled works but selected doesn't.  In the header, it appears that `UIControl` uses a bitfield that has such areas as `selected` (which is a 1-bit field).  If it is an odd number it works correctly, but an even number doesn't.  So the number *must* be 0 or 1 when inserting.  `enabled` is an actual `BOOL` property and is probably stored as a `signed char` instead of a 1-bit field.

Comment: Interesting related reading: [BOOL's sharp corners](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/564-bools-sharp-corners/), at the BNR blog.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks, I actually found my way to that already!!  It was very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not assigning a boolean YES or NO to the button:

```
kMenu.eraserButton.selected = ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode & SO2DrawModeEraser);
```

You are assigning the result of a bitwise operation to the button. So, ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode & SO2DrawModeEraser) is either a zero or non-zero value. For zero value, it will work as boolean NO is also 0. But for non-zero value that is not equal to 1, it is not the same as boolean YES (which is equal to 1). Testing will give a boolean result, but assigning value is different.

For example:

```
int x = 2;
BOOL y;
...
if(x == 2)
    y = YES;
```

is not the same as

```
y = x;    /* x is 2 */
```

You should use the following line which check for non-zero result (not boolean) and return a boolean YES to the button.

```
kMenu.eraserButton.selected = ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode & SO2DrawModeEraser)? YES : NO;
```

Or do u mean to use this:

```
kMenu.eraserButton.selected = ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode && SO2DrawModeEraser);
```

Note the "&&" for logical AND instead of bitwise AND.

Comment: Well how about that!  I always thought that 0 would equate to false and non-zero would equate to true.  In the line above you test the expression as a `BOOL` so why can't the result be used as a `BOOL`?  That's what I would really like to know.  However, it did fix it so I will accept this answer (would still like someone to explain the above follow-up question though).

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: This one -> ([SO2Settings settings].drawMode & SO2DrawModeEraser)? YES : NO  Also, in an interesting development this code **works** is I am setting eraserButton.enabled instead of eraserButton.selected.  It also works if I cast the result to a c-style bool first (but not an obj-c BOOL).

Comment: Yes, this line will work for any receptor that accepts boolean. See my edited answer for the explanation.

Comment: I believe I found out why enabled works but selected doesn't (see my edited question above).  It seems that selected only uses 1-bit inside a bitfield, while enabled uses 8 because it is not in a bitfield.  So if the scalar value is even, the result will be `NO` for but odd numbers will be `YES` due to overflow of `selected`.  `enabled` is stored as an actual `BOOL` so it won't overflow like that.

Comment: @borrrden Thanks, I did not realize the difference in the bits between selected and enabled. I prefer to assign YES and NO to both properties explicitly to avoid intermittent outcomes like you mentioned – zero and even number will be NO, odd number will be YES.

Answer (score 0):

This might be dumb, but I'll say it just to be sure:
In the first line aren't you just checking whether the object is initialized?

```
NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something"];
NSLog(@"%@",st ? @"YES":@"NO");
```

...will still print `YES` but it doesn't mean its value is YES.
Just checking.

Comment: If the first line were uninitialized, then drawMode would be 0, and it would evaluate to `NO`.  Settings is a shared object, and is alive through the application (in this case it is returning 8).  In any case, the problem is it is returning `YES`, but somehow `selected` remains `NO`.